# How to access sdcard using Guon mobile StorageService?

Tags: android, gluon-mobile

How to access sdcard using Guon mobile StorageService ?

In my app I'd like to give the user the opportunity to create a folder 
to later save application specific files. The user should be able to
choose whether to create the folder in the internal storage or the sdcard (if present).

During the implementation I found that I can not access the sdcard using the Gluon mobile StorageService.
Here is the relevant code part I used for testing:

```
Optional<StorageService> oss = Services.get(StorageService.class);
if(oss.isPresent()) {
    StorageService ss = oss.get();
    Optional<File> of = ss.getPublicStorage("/sdcard");
    if(of.isPresent()) {
        File dir = of.get();
        if(dir != null) {
            String s = null;
            if(!dir.exists())
                s = "sdcard dir does not exist";
            String[] list = dir.list();
            int i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Via USB debugging I see the following contents of the variables :

[image]

So there is probably something wrong in my way to access the sdcard.
How can sdcard being accessed using Guon mobile StorageService ?

I use Gluon mobile StorageService 3.8.6.

Comment: Do you have any error logs?

Comment: Uuuh! It's so long ago. I had given up to find a solution for the sdcard and just used the internal storage.